Web Components: How can I select a text node from a slot?
I can select the contents of the follow web component slot by targeting the <p> element (querySelector('p')).
<template>
  <slot>
    <p>I can select this content using querySelector('p'); as it is an HTML Element</p>
  </slot>
</template>

However, I can't seem to select the slot contents when all it contains is a text node, without a surrounding HTML element.
<template>
  <p>
    <slot>I can't seem to select this direct text node.</slot>
  </p>
</template>

It is possible to select the contents of a slot when it just contains a text node?

The slotted content from lightDOM you mean? The code you show would be the default content for a slot (without slotted content)

Not 100% sure what you are after

The slotchange Event fires on all slotted content,
assignedNodes gets you the Nodes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/assignedNodes


.wholeText gets you the text

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/wholeText
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/splitText


But ::slotted can not target Text nodes (neither can CSS)

::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot





<get-slot>Hello, World!</get-slot>
<get-slot>Text in <!-- comment--> TWO text nodes</get-slot>
<get-slot><b>Slotted HTML Node text example!</b></get-slot>

<script>
customElements.define('get-slot', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    const createElement = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
    super().attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).append(
      createElement('style', {
        innerHTML: `
          :host {display:block;padding:.5em;background:lightgreen;border:1px solid green }
          ::slotted(*) { color:blue }
          ::slotted(:first-child) { background:gold }
        `
      }),
      createElement('slot', {
        onslotchange: () => {
          const nodes = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot').assignedNodes();
          console.log(nodes.length, nodes[0].wholeText, nodes[1]?.wholeText);
        }
      })
    );
  }
});
</script>




I've figured out how to get it to render in the light DOM, rather than the shadow DOM, so I can now get the content. Many thanks for the suggestion in your comment and the above post.

So that was this.textContent I presume (innerHTML and innerText are slower)
